# Displaying value of index[0] for second occurrence of two consecutive zeroes in index[1]

Tags: python, pandas

**Question/Context**: I am trying to make a code that will read each CSV file in the specified folder, look for the second consecutive occurrence of zero in column index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Yr1.png), and display the corresponding value from column index [0] when found. Below is what I have so far but it is not working. It simply says that there are no columns with two consecutive zeroes. However, when I open the individual files, I can clearly see that there are columns with two consecutive zeroes. **I have asked this question before and gotten results that worked, until I subbed in my own dataframes. Perhaps it is because my own dataframes contains both numbers and words?**

---

**Dataframe**:

[image: see dataframe]

### | Trial #| 0|
| Unnamed: 0 | filename |
| 0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 0.0|
| 6 | 1.0|
| 7 | 1.0|
| 8 | 1.0 |
| 9 | 1.0 |
| 10 | 0.0 |
| 11 | 0.0 |
| 12 | 1.0 |
| 13 | 0.0 |
| 14 | 1.0 |
| 15 | 1.0 |

**Current code**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = "/content/drive/session 1 & 2"

def find_column1_value_for_second_zero(file_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        consecutive_zeros = 0
        column1_value = None

        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            if row.iloc[1] == 0:
                consecutive_zeros += 1
                if consecutive_zeros == 2:
                    column1_value = row.iloc[0]
                    break
            else:
                consecutive_zeros = 0

        return column1_value
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading file '{file_path}': {str(e)}")
        return None

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):  # Assuming your files are CSV format
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        
        column1_value = find_column1_value_for_second_zero(file_path)
        
        if column1_value is not None:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', the value in column 1 for the second zero in column 2 is: {column1_value}")
        else:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', no second zero in column 2 was found.")
```

---

**Expected Result**: get the value in column [0] that is in the same row as the second consecutive zero in column [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Yr1.png). In the above dataframe it should be returning '11'.

---

**Actual Result**: each row returned "no second zero in column 2 was found."

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your complicated loop, use vectorial code.

Assuming this example input:

```
    col1  col2 col3
0      0     0    A
1      1     1    B
2      2     0    C
3      3     1    D
4      4     1    E
5      5     0    F
6      6     0    G  # should be selected
7      7     0    H
8      8     1    I
9      9     0    K
10    10     0    L  # should be selected
```

Use a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 2         # nth consecutive 0 to select
col = 'col2'  # target column

grp = df[col].ne(0).cumsum()      # form groups
cnt = df.groupby(grp).cumcount()  # enumerate 0s
out = df[cnt.eq(N)]               # select nth
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2 col3
6      6     0    G
10    10     0    L
```

Intermediates:

```
    col1  col2 col3  grp  cnt  cnt.eq(N)
0      0     0    A    0    0      False
1      1     1    B    1    0      False
2      2     0    C    1    1      False
3      3     1    D    2    0      False
4      4     1    E    3    0      False
5      5     0    F    3    1      False
6      6     0    G    3    2       True
7      7     0    H    3    3      False
8      8     1    I    4    0      False
9      9     0    K    4    1      False
10    10     0    L    4    2       True
```

Comment: That's a different approach but a more efficient one in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution based on what I think your CSV is:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import csv

folder_path = '.'

def find_column1_value_for_second_zero(file_path):
    with open(file_path, newline='') as f:
        consec = 0
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            try: x, y = row[0], float(row[1])
            except ValueError: continue
            consec = 0 if y != 0 else consec + 1
            if consec == 2: return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    for filename in Path(folder_path).glob('*csv'):
        column1_value = find_column1_value_for_second_zero(filename.resolve())
        if column1_value:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', the value in column 1 for the second zero in column 2 is: {column1_value}")
        else:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', no second zero in column 2 was found.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).